# Underfined reference clock_gettime not solved by -lrt

Tags: c++, compiling

I'm trying to compile the program the source for which is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XFCE_simple_Network_Monitor_applet).  As per his instructions I'm compiling using the command `g++ -O3 -lrt netmon.cpp -o netmon`.  I get this output:

```
netmon.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb3): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is odd as I have [read](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88108) that the rt library provides this function.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` and `g++` can be picky about the order of link arguments. In general, you should specify library arguments (`-l`) after local objects. Try this instead:

```
g++ -O3 netmon.c -o netmon -lrt
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either.  I eventually compiled with gcc instead and that worked.  Very strange.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used `gcc` instead and it worked:

```
gcc -o netmon netmon.cpp -lrt
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add -lrt **after** the source file, example:

```
g++ -O3 -o netmon netmon.cpp -lrt
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418157/ubuntu-linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-clock-gettime-and-clock-settim) is an other discussion about the same problem.